# select unic ctn and group them by region

Tags: sql, hive

I have 3 tables

sub

```
ctn  region
1    a
1    a
2    b
3    c
8    n
```

mta

```
ctn
1   
1   
2   
3 
4
```

rcr

```
ctn
1   
1   
2   
3 
4  
5
```

I need to find the number of distinct users in every region. In this case the result would be

res

```
a  1
b  1
c  1
n  1
null 2
```

if the user isn't in any region then I need to know how many of users like him there are.

What I have so far.

```
WITH com as(
  SELECT DISTINCT ctn
  FROM (
    SELECT ctn
    FROM mta
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ctn
    FROM rcr
  ) c
)
, distinct_ctn as(
  SELECT DISTINCT sub.ctn, com.ctn, sub.region
  FROM sub
  FULL JOIN com
  ON sub.ctn = com.ctn
)
SELECT region, count(*)
FROM distinct_ctn
GROUP BY region;
```

Comment: What is a user?

Answer (score 0):

Have a sub-query where you use `UNION` to get the distinct cnt values from mta and rcr tables.

`RIGHT JOIN` table sub with that result, and finally `GROUP BY` the join result.

```
select s.region, count(distinct u.ctn)
from sub s
right join (select ctn from mta
            union
            select ctn from rcr) u
   on s.ctn = u.ctn
group by s.region
```

Comment: Won't this only count distinct ctns from mta and rcr? what if there's a ctn in sub not present in other tables? What if there are 2 rows with user 1 in sub? Right join would mean 2 identical rows then. And grouping will return the wrong result.

Comment: Add some more sample data to make things a bit trickier, and also adjust the expected result. Then see if the query still works. (Hard to know exactly what you're looking for...)